# Conditional class in Marko JS Template

Tags: node.js, template-engine, marko

I am using the `layout` taglib to *extend* a page to its template but i don't know how to pass a variable to the main layout and apply a conditional class.

Considering this is my `main-layout.marko`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body class="#### (TITLE === 'REGISTER')?'ACTIVE':'INACTIVE' ####">
    <layout-placeholder name="title"/>
    <layout-placeholder name="body"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

this is my `registration.marko`

```
<layout-use template="./layout.marko">
    <layout-put into="title">
      $data.title
    </layout-put>
    <layout-put into="body">
      some content
    </layout-put>
</layout-use>
```

and finally this is the code I use to render the page and pass the title data

```
router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  registration.render({
    title: 'register'
  }, res);
});
```

How can I create a conditional class on the `main-layout.marko` file that switches between *active* or *inactive* depending on the page title?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass data to a layout by adding additional attributes to your `<layout-use>` tag. See: [marko-layout » Layout Data](https://github.com/marko-js/marko-layout#layout-data)

For your example, the following will work:

In `main-layout.marko`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body class="#### ${data.title === 'REGISTER' ? 'ACTIVE' : 'INACTIVE' } ####">
    <layout-placeholder name="title">
      ${data.title}
    </layout-placeholder>
    <layout-placeholder name="body"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

In `registration.marko`:

```
<layout-use template="./layout.marko" title="${data.title}">
    <layout-put into="body">
      some content
    </layout-put>
</layout-use>
```

That should solve your problem, but let me know if you are still stuck.

Comment: It surely works thanks! What's the difference between the ternary condition you wrote and this one `{?data.title === 'register';active;inactive}` ?

Comment: Good question, @crash. They compile down to the same thing so it is only syntax difference. See: http://markojs.com/try-online/#Conditionals_Shorthand_Conditionals When using the `{? ... }` syntax, the alternative clause is optional unlike with a JavaScript ternary conditional. In the next major version of Marko we plan on dropping support for the custom Marko `{? ... }` syntax to simplify the language and to be closer to JavaScript. In Marko v3, an attribute value will always be a valid JavaScript expression. See: https://github.com/marko-js/marko/issues/90

Answer (score -2):

there is another  way  of  passing  data  t  all of  its  template   that  is  using  $global   in  which  you are  passing  your  data  .

and  after  using  global  you  dont need  to   add attribute  to any  tag  .  you can access  it  by  using  like 
out.global.username